# How to prevent mismatched IDs in GraphQL

Tags: graphql

One of the standard practices in GraphQL is to use an ID scalar as a global id for any record.
This makes sense but leaves me wondering how to best ensure the client uses the 'correct' id in arguments or mutations or would know which one to use.

```
query {
 Books(id: ID) {
  id: ID!
  name: Text!
  pages: Int!
  }
 DVDs(id: ID) {
  id: ID!
  name: Text!
  }
}
mutations {
  removePageFromBook(id ID) {
    sadBook: Book!
  }
}
```

with the schema above it's obvious that we don't want to invoke `removePageFromBook` with an ID the represents a DVD, but only an ID the represents a Book.

The problem however is that this is only clear because of naming, which is something that can be avoided in most other GraphQL scenarios and is against the spirit of it.  Especially when the schema gets larges this Becomes harder and harder to communicate effectively.

So are there any good ways to handle this issue?
(and related would it be better to return null or error out if someone tries to remove a page from a DVD)

(in our current situation we know on the server what type an ID 'really' represents ala `base64("book:123")` )

Answer (score 0):

If i'm understanding your problem correctly, the answer is (sadly) no. This would actually be a great use case for generics, but that proposal is currently dead in the water.

Answer (score 0):

> One of the standard practices in GraphQL is to use an ID scalar as a global id for any record.

`Global` is not a good assumption here. Usually, it is a type related id. Not global, not unique.

> (in our current situation we know on the server what type an ID 'really' represents ala base64("book:123") )

... then it's a part of the [materialized] implementation ... and **you already have unique AND type related ids**

... in your `removePageFromBook` mutation resolver you know that you should use [in db/sql query] an `id` constructed from `book` type and `args.id` ... to affect[/work on] `book` types[/records] only ... **there is no risk of a mismatch here ... as you can't affect an unrelated, other record[/types]**

... using repository/ORM/other DB abstraction layer you can use it [type+id matching] behind the scene

`WPGraphQL` (WordPress plugin) implements a slightly different solution for Custom Post Types [f.e.] derived from `Post` type. Posts, stored in `posts` table has `id` [DB field], unique per table [autoincrement] but not derived [any] type related as it's int only (used in DB relations). By default `WPGraphQL` exposes an `id` as **globally unique type related** prop, unique for all possible types/tables, not post derived types only. It internally resolves to DB [int] `id` and is used to type matching (f.e. if mutation input type must be specific CPT related). Alternatively you can use 'human readable' `databaseId` ... now (new release) you can use `id` plus `idType` enum (`DATABASE_ID`, `ID`, `URI`, `SLUG`).

### conclusion

You can use globally unique type related `id` on GraphQL API level and internally implement it any way you need using real or virtual data and metadata. It all depends on your stack/layers/libs.

### update

Taking the problem more FE and more generic ... taking again WPGraphQL ... **all mutations have their own input and result/payload types**, e.g. `createComment(input: CreateCommentInput!): CreateCommentPayload`

... however, this doesn't prevent mismatch usage of `id` only ...

... but can help when `removePageFromBookInput` will contain some [specific to books] `pageToRemove`

Comment: This is more or less what we are doing on the back end, but my question is about the frontend knowing somehow what ids it could use (instead of geussing by the name / description)

Comment: Are you expecting some magic or automation to be human readable? ... you can easily decode types from ids inside rendered list/items to enable/disable row actions or scan displayed item list to enable/disable group [button] actions ... you can also do that on validation step just before calling mutation

Comment: I was hoping for some way to express this in the schema, like many other things in GraphQL. The schema makes it impossible to ask the number of pages from a DVD since it doesn't have that field (schema violation), I was hoping to express the same about my mutation (while still keeping a globalid and being relay compatible)